# Flex ComboBox, default value and dataproviders

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, combobox

I have a Flex `ComboBox` that gets populated by a `dataprovider` all is well...

I would now like to add a default " -- select a item --" option at the 0 index, how can I do this and still use a `dataprovider`? I have not seen any examples of such, but I can't imagine this being hard...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you don't need the default item to be selectable you can use the `prompt` property of `ComboBox` and set the `selectedIndex` to -1. That will show the string you set `propmt` to as the selected value until the user chooses another. It will not appear in the list of options, however.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this problem today and wanted to share my solution.

I have a ComboBox that has an ArrayCollection containing Objects as it's dataprovider.  When the application runs, it uses a RemoteObject to go out and get the ArrayCollection/Objects.  In my event handler for that call I just have it append another object to the beginning of the ArrayCollection and select it:

```
var defaultOption:Object = {MyLabelField: "Select One"};
myDataProvider.addItemAt(defaultOption, 0);
myComboBox.selectedIndex = 0;
```

This is what my ComboBox looks like for reference:

```
<mx:ComboBox id="myComboBox" dataProvider="{myDataProvider}" labelField="MyLabelField" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I've dealt with this in the past is to create a new collection to serve as the data provider for the combobox, and then I listen for changes to the original source (using an `mx.BindingUtils.ChangeWatcher`).  When I get such a notification, I recreate my custom data provider.

I wish I knew a better way to approach this; I'll monitor this question just in case.

Answer (score 0):

This can be used following code for selected default value of combobox

```
var index:String = "foo";
for(var objIndex:int = 0; objIndex < comboBox.dataProvider.length; objIndex++) {
  if(comboBox.dataProvider[objIndex].label == index)
  {
     comboBox.selectedIndex = objIndex;
     break;
  }
}
<mx:ComboBox id="comboBox" dataProvider="{_pageIndexArray}" />
```